# Session timeout for authentication in laravel

Tags: laravel, timeout, logout

I keep getting a session timeout during some random times and I have to re login again? I look around and people said to change 'lifetime' => 120 in config/session.php and it was already default there but still getting a timeout. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: If it logs out you when you close a browser, change `expire_on_close` to `false` in `config/session.php`.

Comment: Nope, it logs me out when I am using it half way, could the problem be because I am using more than 2 different accounts to log in?